# How can I detect when a global variable is set in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In javascript, I can detect when a global variable `foo` is set (assuming that it is initially undefined) by using `Object.defineProperty`:

```
var foo_;
Object.defineProperty(window, 'foo', {
  get: function() {
    return foo_;
  },
  set: function(newFoo) {
    console.log('foo set to ' + newFoo);
    foo_ = newFoo;
  }
});
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? One downside is that I cannot call `Object.defineProperty` on the same property twice. Overriding the entire property just to detect when it is defined seems a bit overkill.

Could I somehow use [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)? I feel like I would have to make a proxy that targets the window object though ... is that efficient?

Comment: I think we can check if it is available in window object like `window[foo]`

Comment: I want to detect the moment when the global variable is set and say log something at that time.

Comment: This feels like an async hack. If it is, don't do it. Use a `Promise`

Comment: If you use it for debugging - why does it matter if you cannot set it twice? If you're using it not for debugging - you better don't.

Comment: I'm detecting for debugging purposes, but another library has already called `Object.defineProperty` on that property.

Comment: If it did - just put a breakpoint there.

Comment: I would set up a static analysis tool that logs every access of unknown global variables, and would log expressions of the form `window.x`, `self['y']` etc accesses. It could even log warnings when `window/self/...` is used in every other kind of expression.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Not really. Maybe you could (should) hide `_foo` in a closure instead of creating another global variable.

> One downside is that I cannot call `Object.defineProperty` on the same property twice. Overriding the entire property just to detect when it is defined seems a bit overkill.

The only problem is that you forgot to [pass the `configurable: true` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description).

> Could I somehow use proxies?

No. You cannot replace the global object with a proxy. The only thing you could do is wrap all the code in a `with (new Proxy(…)) { … }` block.

Answer (score -1):

You might also do like

```
var _bar;
window.__defineGetter__("bar", function(){return this._bar});
window.__defineSetter__("bar", function(v){console.log("bar set to:",v); this._bar = v;});
```

Comment: Don't use deprecated and non-standard builtins.