# Proxy on window

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to set up a `Proxy` which warns me when a new property is defined on the `window` object. (Actually I'd like to catch all the global variable declarations)

```
let handler = {
    defineProperty(target, key, descriptor) {
        console.log('hey', key);
        return false;
    }
};
window = new Proxy(window, handler);
window.foo = 'bar';
// nothing happens
```

The code above works for any object but window:

```
let handler = {
    defineProperty(target, key, descriptor) {
        console.log('hey', key);
        return false;
    }
};
let target = {};
target = new Proxy(target, handler);
target.foo = 'bar';
// console: "hey  bar"
```

Is there any way to set up a `Proxy` on the `window` object, and if it's not possible, is there any tricky solution to achieve the same goal?

Comment: No, since you cannot replace window with your proxy.

Comment: Your code should only log for `proxy.foo = 'bar'`, not for `target.foo = 'bar'`. Does what you posted really work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect when a global variable is set in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38759116/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi You have shared the link of dupe, but have not marked/flagged as dupe. Any specific reason?

Comment: @Rajesh Can't close when the target has no upvoted/accepted answers (and I can't upvote my own answer there :-D)

Comment: "warns me when a new property is defined on the window object." if want this feature to be development time I'd recommend you to use a linter for that.

Comment: @Adam do you need it for a specific property or you want to be notified of any changes?

Comment: Any changes, @Hitmands

Comment: you cannot do it... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759116/how-can-i-detect-when-a-global-variable-is-set-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer is no. You can't use a proxy for this.
It is always better to revise and refactor your app to get rid of need to do such shenanigans. But I know that sometimes we have no time to do things right. Althrough I don't recommend you to do this, you still can get a changes on window object.

You have a couple of options to do this.
If you know a list of vars you're looking for, you can use something like [Watch.JS](https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS) Basically it is able to track all the changes, but I wasn't able to make it work reliably so it is better to specify a list

```
watch(window, ['list', 'of', 'vars'], (prop, action, newVal, oldVal) => {
    console.log('Property changed', prop, action, newVal, oldVal);
}, 1);
```

As an alternative, you can create a simple dirty checker

```
let props = Object.keys(window);
const check = () => {
    const currentProps = Object.keys(window);
    const newProps = currentProps.filter(item => props.indexOf(item) === -1);
    if (newProps.length) {
        console.log('Added these properties', newProps);
        props = currentProps;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(check);
};
requestAnimationFrame(check);
```

But in case you decided to go with either solution, you have to make sure all checks will stop when needed to avoid memory leaks, or CPU consumption. 
This check code is not consuming too much but it could in theory. So you have to keep an eye on it.
On empty page profile data looks like this [image: profile data]

And remember to use `unwatch` in case of Watch.JS or to add a condition to stop the checks in case you use the second solution once they will complete the job

Comment: Notice that non-enumerable props are not watched with Object.keys. The performance will be considerably worse when non-enumerable props are watched too.

Comment: @estus This solution is sufficient imo and I have not used `getOwnPropertyNames` to reduce collection size to filter. Since author wanted to just get global variable declarations and not to watch on all window properties.

Comment: window properties can be declared with Object.defineProperty, too. The task becomes much more straightforward when it's known beforehand what are these variables are.

Comment: Using `requestAnimationFrame` is both genius and horrifying, and sadly was the only viable solution to the problem I had.

Answer (score 3):

`Proxy` is slow and shouldn't be used in performance-critical places, while `window` affects the entire application and certainly could be considered performance-critical.

**But the `window` property is [read-only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window#Properties), i.e. it is non-configurable and has no set accessor, it can't be replaced with a proxy.**

The alternative to `Proxy` that can spy on `window` changes is Firefox-specific [`watch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) method, it can be used in scripts that run in Firefox (e.g. extensions) but not anywhere else. V8-specific [`Object.observe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) was unable to observe `window` by design, also, it was removed from Chrome and other V8 browsers.

Generally this can be achieved by polling `window` properties:

```
let oldProps;

setInterval(() => {
  console.time('Polling window');
  let newProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window);

  if (oldProps) {
    let addedProps = newProps.filter(prop => oldProps.indexOf(prop) < 0 );
    console.log('Added props', addedProps);
  }
  oldProps = newProps;
  console.timeEnd('Polling window');
}, 500);
```

If this code is supposed to be used in production, it should be optimized, because `filter` is relatively slow, and `indexOf` traverses the entire array on each iteration, this results in very inefficient code.

Raw `for` or `while` loop is the way to go:

```
let oldProps;

setInterval(() => {
  console.time('Polling window');
  let newProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).sort();

  if (oldProps) {
    for (let oldI = 0, newI = 0; oldI < oldProps.length || newI < newProps.length; oldI++, newI++) {
      let oldProp = oldProps[oldI];
      let newProp = newProps[newI];

      if (newProp > oldProp || newProp === undefined) {
        newI--;
        console.log('Removed prop', oldProp);
      } else if (newProp < oldProp || oldProp === undefined) {
        oldI--;
        console.log('Added prop', newProp);
      }
    }
  }
  oldProps = newProps;
  console.timeEnd('Polling window');
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

Youre actually not trying to trigger the window proxy. You need to do:

```
let proxy = new Proxy(window, handler);
proxy.foo = 'bar';
```

And no, you cant do

```
window = new Proxy(window, handler);
```

as window is unreplaceable.

Comment: +1 for this! Changing anything in the proxy actually modifies the window too (althought only when you define new properties, you cannot override existing in the window)

Answer (score 2):

Yes window is unreplaceable, but you can wrap the tested code with a fake proxified window:

```js
let handler = {
   defineProperty(target, key, descriptor) {
     console.log('hey', key);
     return false;
   }
 };

let proxyWindow = new Proxy(window, handler);

(function(window){
   
 //js
 window.foo = 'bar';

}.bind(proxyWindow,proxyWindow).call(proxyWindow));
```

If the tested code is not too complicated, this will be OK, as leaks to the actual window object may occur (ex: setTimeout etc) but these can be patched too.