# Is there some how to detect changes on the window object?

Tags: reactjs

I;'m working in a project that's uses a custom browser. This custom browser injects an object inside the window object. I need to track the changes...something like...

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.customObject.addListener('onchange' , (changes) => console.log(changes))
}
```

The example above is just hypothetical to make this thing more easy to understand. Is there some how to archive it ?

Comment: Are you able to edit the code which injects the object? If so, you could fire an event when that happened and listen for it.

Comment: I've plans to check this today...I am just preparing myself for the worst scenario.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proxy on window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437583/proxy-on-window)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can observe dom changes with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) api.

```
var observeDOM = (function(){
  var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

  return function( obj, callback ){
    if( !obj || !obj.nodeType === 1 ) return; // validation

    if( MutationObserver ){
      // define a new observer
      var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer){
        if( mutations[0].addedNodes.length || mutations[0].removedNodes.length )
          callback( mutations[0] );
      });
      // have the observer observe foo for changes in children
      obs.observe( obj, { childList:true, subtree:true });
    }

    else if( window.addEventListener ){
      obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', callback, false);
      obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', callback, false);
    }
  }
})();
```

Usage example:

```
// Observe a specific DOM element:
observeDOM(document.querySelector('body'), function(m) { 
  console.log('Added:', m.addedNodes, 'Removed:', m.removedNodes);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Olim ! But looks like this just apply to DOM changes, correct ? Can't be used to track changes on the window object...am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. There was a proposal for adding Observable API for js objects, but it is now obsolete. https://esdiscuss.org/topic/an-update-on-object-observe