# Can I use JavaScript ES6 Proxy to observe when an object is created

Tags: javascript, proxy

I would like to be able to observe when a global object gets created.

I was hoping to do something with JavaScript Proxy.

```
let objectA = undefined;

...  Proxy code here
```

A little while later...

```
objectA = { prop1: 'hello', prop2: 'world' }

... proxy code gets called here... console.log(objectA)
```

Comment: Not if you're creating your object as a literal like that, no. If you have a `class` or a function with a constructor, you can use the [`construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/construct) trap.

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759116/how-can-i-detect-when-a-global-variable-is-set-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to be able to observe when a global object gets created. I was hoping to do something with JavaScript Proxy.

No, `Proxy` doesn't do that. A proxy is an already existing object, and you cannot wrap the global object (`window`) in a proxy either.

You could however install a setter on `window`.